# Can't find ViewModelProviders class, only ViewModelProvider

Tags: kotlin, viewmodel

I am trying to create lifecycle-aware view models. But I can't find `ViewModelProviders` class in my Android project, only `ViewModelProvider`. There seems to be no `android.arch.lifecycle.ViewModelProviders` package for me to import as well. What's happening

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You probably have this dependency included in your project:

```
implementation "android.arch.lifecycle:viewmodel:$lifecycle_version"
```

That contains `ViewModelProvider` (and just 4 other classes), but `ViewModelProviders` is in a different package:

```
implementation "android.arch.lifecycle:extensions:$lifecycle_version"
```

Here are the contents of these packages for reference (as of version 1.1.1):

[image: The contents of the extensions and viewmodel packages]

---

For the record, you can find this out yourself by looking up the docs for the [`ViewModelProviders`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/arch/lifecycle/ViewModelProviders) class, where it says up top:

> added in version 1.1.0
>
> belongs to Maven artifact android.arch.lifecycle:extensions:1.1.1

Comment: Thanks. Here is some more detailed info about adding `LifeCycle` components into your project https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/adding-components#lifecycle

Comment: With API 29, the architecture components have been moved to the `androidx.*` namespace. You should therefore use `implementation "androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-extensions:$lifecycleVersion"` and `implementation "androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-viewmodel:$lifecycleVersion"`. At the time of writing this, using `$lifecycleVersion='2.0.0-rc1'` will work. Note that the libs are backwards compatible, so this will also work for apps with API compatibility < 29.

Answer (score 4):

Also, just for future reference.

`ViewModelProviders` class is now deprecated.
According to Android Developers Documentation: [ViewModelProviders](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/lifecycle/ViewModelProviders.html)

> This class is deprecated. Use the constructors for ViewModelProvider
>   directly.

Comment: This should be the new right answer!